# Can't save values in dataStore

Tags: lua, roblox

Every value saves besides of StrMulti and probably EndMulti, ChakraMulti.
It just doesn't save at all. :c
(.............................................................................................)
(I need letters to post this. Ai doesn't want me to post this)
(Still can't post. Sorry for this extra text)

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local ServerStorage
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local dataStore1 = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Test")

local function waitForRequestBudget(requestType)
    local currentBudget = DataStoreService:GetRequestBudgetForRequestType(requestType)
    while currentBudget < 1 do
        currentBudget = DataStoreService:GetRequestBudgetForRequestType(requestType)
        task.wait(5)
    end
end

local function setupPlayerData(player: player)

    local userID = player.UserId
    local key = "Player_"..userID
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local Multi = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    Multi.Name = "Multi"
    Multi.Value = 1

    local rep = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    rep.Name = "rep"
    rep.Value = 0

    local agZone = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    agZone.Name = "agZone"
    agZone.Value = 1

    local jfZone = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    jfZone.Name = "jfZone"
    jfZone.Value = 1

    local eMulti = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    eMulti.Name = "eMulti"
    eMulti.Value = 1

    local Title = Instance.new("StringValue", leaderstats)
    Title.Name = "Title"
    Title.Value = "Innocent"


    local eMultic = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    eMultic.Name = "eMultic"
    eMultic.Value = 1

    local Agility = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    Agility.Name = "Agility"
    Agility.Value = 90

    local JumpForce = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    JumpForce.Name = "JumpForce"
    JumpForce.Value = 0

    local AgMulti = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    AgMulti.Name = "AgMulti"
    AgMulti.Value = 1

    local jfMulti = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    jfMulti.Name = "jfMulti"
    jfMulti.Value = 1

    local Chakra = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    Chakra.Name = "Chakra"
    Chakra.Value = 0

    local ZoneMulti = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    ZoneMulti.Name = "ZoneMulti"
    ZoneMulti.Value = 1

    local eZoneMulti = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    eZoneMulti.Name = "eZoneMulti"
    eZoneMulti.Value = 1

    local Strength = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    Strength.Name = "Strength" 
    Strength.Value = 100

    local endZone = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    endZone.Name = "endZone"
    endZone.Value = 1

    local strZone = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    strZone.Name = "strZone"
    strZone.Value = 1


    local ChakraZone = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    ChakraZone.Name = "ChakraZone"
    ChakraZone.Value = 1

    local StrMulti = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    StrMulti.Name = "StrMulti"
    StrMulti.Value = 1

    local EndMulti = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    EndMulti.Name = "EndMulti"
    EndMulti.Value = 1

    local ChakraMulti = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    ChakraMulti.Name = "ChakraMulti"
    ChakraMulti.Value = 1

    local Endurance = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    Endurance.Name = "Endurance"
    Endurance.Value = 0

    local Yen = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    Yen.Name = "Yen"
    Yen.Value = 0

    local powers = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    powers.Name = "Powers"

    local hasAura = Instance.new("BoolValue", powers)
    hasAura.Name = "hasAura"
    hasAura.Value = true

    local str4Q = Instance.new("NumberValue", player)
    str4Q.Name = "Str4Q"
    str4Q.Value = 0

    local quest = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    quest.Name = "QuestNum"
    quest.Value = 1

    local success, returnValue
    repeat

        waitForRequestBudget(Enum.DataStoreRequestType.GetAsync)
        success, returnValue = pcall(dataStore1.GetAsync,dataStore1, key)

    until success or not Players:FindFirstChild(player.Name)

    success, returnValue = pcall(dataStore1.GetAsync,dataStore1, key)
    if success then
        if returnValue == nil then
            returnValue = {
                Endurance = 0,
                Strength = 0,
                Chakra = 0,
                Yen = 0,
                Agility = 0,
                JumpForce = 0,
                rep = 0,
                ChakraMulti = 0,
                StrMulti = 0,
                EndMulti = 0

            }
        end

        Strength.Value = if returnValue.Strength ~= nil then returnValue.Strength else 0
        Yen.Value = if returnValue.Yen ~= nil then returnValue.Yen else 0
        Endurance.Value = if returnValue.Endurance ~= nil then returnValue.Endurance else 0
        Chakra.Value = if returnValue.Chakra ~= nil then returnValue.Chakra else 0
        Agility.Value = if returnValue.Agility ~= nil then returnValue.Agility else 0
        JumpForce.Value = if returnValue.JumpForce ~= nil then returnValue.JumpForce else 0
        rep.Value = if returnValue.rep ~= nil then returnValue.rep else 0
        ChakraMulti.Value = if returnValue.ChakraMulti ~= nil then returnValue.ChakraMulti else 0
        EndMulti.Value = if returnValue.EndMulti ~= nil then returnValue.EndMulti else 0
        StrMulti.Value = if returnValue.StrMulti ~= nil then returnValue.StrMulti else 0


    else
        player:Kick("There was an error loading your Data. Roblox's DataStore might be down, try again later, or contact us!")
        print(player.Name.."Data loading Error!")
    end

end

local function save(player)
    local userID = player.UserId
    local key = "Player_"..userID

    local strength = player.Strength.Value
    local yen = player.Yen.Value
    local endurance = player.Endurance.Value
    local chakra = player.Chakra.Value
    local agility = player.Agility.Value
    local jumpforce = player.JumpForce.Value
    local Rep = player.rep.Value
    local strmulti = player.StrMulti.Value
    local endmulti = player.EndMulti.Value
    local chakramulti = player.ChakraMulti.Value
    local dataTable = {
        Strength = strength,
        Yen = yen,
        Endurance = endurance,
        Chakra = chakra,
        Agility = agility,
        JumpForce = jumpforce,  
        rep = Rep,
        ChakraMulti = chakramulti,
        EndMulti = endmulti,
        StrMulti = strmulti
    }

    print(dataTable)

    local success, returnValue
    repeat
        waitForRequestBudget(Enum.DataStoreRequestType.GetAsync)
        success, returnValue = pcall(dataStore1.UpdateAsync, dataStore1, key, function()
            return dataTable
        end)
    until success 

    if success then
        print("Data Saved!")
    else 
        print("Data saving Error!")
    end
end

local function onShutDown()
    if RunService:IsStudio() then
        task.wait(2)
    else
        local finished = Instance.new("BindableEvent")
        local allPlayers = Players:GetPlayers()
        local leftPlayers = #allPlayers

        for _, player in ipairs(allPlayers) do
            coroutine.wrap(function()
                save(player)
                leftPlayers -=1
                if leftPlayers == 0 then 
                    finished:Fire()

                end
            end)
        end
        finished.Event:Wait()
    end
end

for _, player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    coroutine.wrap(setupPlayerData)(player)
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(setupPlayerData)
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(save)
game:BindToClose(onShutDown)

while true do 
    task.wait(300)
    for _, player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
        coroutine.wrap(save)(player)
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you seeing any of the messages you are logging?

Comment: `Strength.Value = if returnValue.Strength ~= nil then returnValue.Strength else 0` is not very idiomatic in lua, you should do something like `Strength.Value = returnValue.Strength ~= nil and returnValue.Strength or 0`